# how can I set a pyspark dataframe map value where the value is a struct?

Tags: pyspark

I am using PySpark and I have a dataframe which is a map structure:

```
>>> myMap.printSchema()
root
 |-- key: string (nullable = false)
 |-- value: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- field1: boolean (nullable = true)
 |    |-- field2: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- field3: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- field4: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- field5: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- field6: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- field7: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- field8: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- field9: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- field10: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- field11: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- field12: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- field13: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- field14: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- field15: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- field16: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- field17: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- field18: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- field19: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- field20: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- field21: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- field22: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- field23: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- field24: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- field25: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- field26: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- field27: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- field28: string (nullable = true)
```

There are three keys in the map, and I want to populate key1 and key3 with the value in key2

```
>>> myMap.select('*').show()
+----+--------------------+
| key|               value|
+----+--------------------+
|key1|            [false,]|
|key2|[true, [, data...   |
|key3|            [false,]|
+----+--------------------+
```

I started by extracting the value for key2

```
>>> value2 = myMap.filter(col('key') == 'key2').select('value')
>>> value2
DataFrame[value: struct<field0:boolean,field1:struct<field2:string,field3:string,...SNIP...>>>]
```

and tried to use it to create a dataframe with this value for key1, but I get an error

```
>>> myMap.filter(col('key') == 'key1').withColumn('value', value2)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/RVA/software/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py", line 2095, in withColumn
    assert isinstance(col, Column), "col should be Column"
AssertionError: col should be Column
```

I tried a few different things but to no avail.  How can I create a dataframe where key1 and key3 in this map have the same value as key2?

Answer (score 1):

The return type of value2 in your code is a Dataframe. The withColumn method doesn't take dataframe as its second parameter. It accepts a literal.
Hence, your code for value2 must be as follows:

```
value2 = myMap.filter(col('key') == 'key2').select('value').first().value
```

The rest of the code must be as follows:

```
myMap.filter(col('key') != 'key2').withColumn('val_x', lit(value2))
myMap.show()

+----+--------+--------------------+
| key|   value|               val_x|
+----+--------+--------------------+
|key1|[false,]|[true, [, data...   |
|key3|[false,]|[true, [, data...   |
+----+--------+--------------------+
```

Comment: Thank you, but I get an error when I try that: py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.sql.functions.lit.
: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unsupported literal type class java.util.ArrayList [true, [null, data1, data2, data3, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, []]]
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.Literal$.apply(literals.scala:88)